# 21.5" Late 2012 iMac | Display or GPU issue

Tags: display, imac, gpu

I purchased used iMac over auction. The iMac seems to show no picture. Could this be the display pin issue or it has the like of faulty GPU?

Since these iMacs don't have screen mirroring by default, is there any way to do that to see if its GPU or display issue. I am attaching the pictures below:

[image]
[image]

More then half screen is black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without putting hands on, it's impossible to know for sure if it's a GPU or an LCD issue. However, a screen that has a delineated bright area and a dead area will most likely be the display panel and not the GPU.

It's not clear what you mean by  a "display pin issue," but if you're referencing an issue with the display LVDS cable, then no, it won't be related to a faulty cable.

If you have another Mac available, you can put this one into [Target Disk Mode](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/transfer-files-mac-computers-target-disk-mode-mchlp1443/mac) and use that Mac to boot off the iMac's internal drive.  You can then configure display mirroring and remote control (VNC) so that the next time you boot the iMac (normally), you'll be able to better diagnose it

Comment: I did mean LVDS cable being faulty if someone pulls it improperly. Anyways could you expand the last paragraph you wrote. I can connect two iMacs using thunderbolt cable, how would I be able to configure display mirroring and remote control (VNC) Also what do you mean next time I boot the iMac I will be able to better diagnose it? Will it be automatically mirrored to external display?

Comment: One more thing, can I install the MacOS using Target Disk Mode? It might have had wiped out hard-disk

Comment: Boot *another* Mac using the iMac's drives as the boot device via TDM. Make your changes (enable Mirroring, remote access, etc.) then boot the iMac normally. If the main screen doesn't work you can either see the screen via external monitor or you can remote into it. Yes, you can install Mac OS using TDM

Comment: A broken LVDS cable is usually no  video at all. You have to open it up to find out if someone attempted a repair so, again, you have to put hands on, but in my experience, very unlikely.

Comment: Allan, this is massive help! Thanks a lot!. The hard drive seems to be wiped out so no OS is there. If I use my working 27" imac 2017 to install the OS to 21.5" imac 2012, will I get any compatibility issues? Cause I guess the 2017 model might load its own drivers into the target disk or something?

Comment: You have to use an OS compatible to both the 2017 and the 2012.  Since Catalina works on both, you should have no problems.  macOS installs *all* drivers (kexts) necessary regardless of hardware.  Windows installs drivers based on hardware, macOS doesn't have to.   Windows "selects" which drivers to install because there is vastly much more hardware permutations than macOS.

Comment: Awesome, Its great to learn how Apple manages the drivers across various families of hardware! Kudos for mentioning that! I am currently using Mojave so I guess it should be fine for both.

Comment: You should be fine!